# Cannot switch to a non-admin user

Tags: raspbian, su

Seems like I can't su unless the user is admin.
When trying to ssh into the user or `su username` i get:
`Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied`

Have tried almost every solution I could find on the Interwebz, none worked. Help pls :(
OS: Raspbian

Comment: Please give the exact command you typed, and the complete output.

Comment: and add also the output of `ls -l /bin/bash`, there might be something hosed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `su username`
Then it ofc asked me to input the password for the user, when I did that I got:
`Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied`    
    
@RadovanGarabík Output of ls -l /bin/bash:     
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 813992 Sep 25  2014 bash`

Comment: Ok, but update the question with additional information, please. And what you describe (if I understand it correctly) is normal behavior. What were you expecting?

Comment: Maybe there's a difference between `su username` and `su - username` but this also happens if I try to ssh into the machine using the same user.

Comment: `/bin/bash` should not be writable by group and certainly not by other.  If you've messed up the perms on `/bin/bash`, it's possible that you've also messed up the perms on other important system files, including the libraries that bash depends upon (check with, e.g., `ldd /bin/bash | awk '/=>/ {print $3}' | xargs ls -ldH`.  My guess is that you've somehow made those libs readable by admin, but not by other users.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you're user abc and you want to switch to user pqr

```
$ whoami
abc
$ su - pqr
password:
```

You should now have switched to user pqr

Comment: I'm just trying to switch to the user, not make it superuser... :/

Comment: `su - username` gives:    
`No directory, logging in with HOME=/
Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied
*** glibc detected *** su: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00017264 ***`

Comment: first visudo and make the changes as suggested earlier. then try this, again. Give all privileges to both users.

Comment: I did. Still getting the error above. :(

Comment: do `ls /home` and see if you can see the user you intend to switch to.

Comment: Don't see it. Only the admin users folders...

Comment: @SlimeyStuff how about `# ls /home/` ? (if you didn't run it as root last time)